# Error when using round() for a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, rounding, typeerror

I never coded before and started with Python-3.5 a few days ago.
After some exercise i try to play around myself.
Last time I wanted to create a script which stores the input as a variable and rounds it to three decimals. Unfortunately I get an error when I try to do that:

```
round (spam, 3)
TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method"
```

I tried to look this up in the Q&A but you guys seem to have more complex problems related to this error msg.

So this is what I entered in the file editor when I got the error msg:

```
print('Pls enter value')
spam = input()
#print(spam)
round(spam, 3)
```

when I enter the following in the interactive shell the rounding seems to work though:

```
>>> spam = 3.666666
>>> round (spam, 3)
3.667
```

So why is the same logic working in the shell but not in the File editor ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the second case you supply the value of `spam` using a float literal (that is, `spam = 3.666666`)  while, in the first case you get it from calling `input()` which isn't exactly the same.

The function `input()` returns a `str` instance in Python 3 and, for `str` types, the `round` function doesn't make much sense; you need to explicitly transform it to a float by wrapping the result of `input()` with `float()`:

```
spam = float(input())  # change input to 'float' type
```

Now, you can call `round` on it. You *do need* to be careful that the input you actually supply is indeed transformable to a `float` or else a `ValueError` will be raised.

In addition to that, no need to add the `print` call before `input`, `input` has a `prompt` argument that allows you to specify text before submitting input:

```
spam = input("Enter valid float number: ")
```

You should now get similar results for both cases.

Comment: Many thanks Jim! It's all clear now!
I only had the print call before the input because i wanted to see whether the entered value was really assigned to the variable. So it was only for checking purpose...